# Por que el el programa manda el correo multiples veces al destinatario en funcion al valor de X?

Tags: php, phpmailer

Cuando entra el ciclo for el programa le manda un solo correo a la primera posicion del arrelgo $lista, luego cuando el ciclo se repite por segunda vez el programa le manda el mensaje dos veces al correo en la 2da posicion del arreglo. Cuando entra por 3era vez en el ciclo, el programa el manda 3 mensajes al correo en la 3era posicion del arreglo. Me pregunta es porque? Aqui les dejo el codigo

```
<?php
$asunto = $_POST["asunto"];
$mensaje = $_POST["mensaje"];
$lista = array("gerardo.topete@outlook.com","gerardotopete7@gmail.com","suscripcion.punkconleche@gmail.com");
$i = count($lista);

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require 'PHPMailer/Exception.php';
require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailer.php';
require 'PHPMailer/SMTP.php';

// Instantiation and passing `true` enables exceptions
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);


for($x = 0; $x < $i; $x++){
    try {
        //Server settings
        $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;                                       // Enable verbose debug output
        $mail->isSMTP();                                            // Set mailer to use SMTP
        $mail->Host       = 'smtp.gmail.com';                       // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
        $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   // Enable SMTP authentication
        $mail->Username   = '********';   // SMTP username
        $mail->Password   = '********';                         // SMTP password
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                                  // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
        $mail->Port       = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to

        //Recipients
        $mail->setFrom('suscripcion.punkconleche@gmail.com');
        $mail->addAddress($lista[$x]);     // Add a recipient

        // Content
        $mail->isHTML(true);                                       // Set email format to HTML
        $mail->Subject = $asunto;
        $mail->Body    = $mensaje;

        $mail->send();
        echo 'Tu correo se ha enviado';
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo 'Error al intentar suscribirte: ', $mail->ErrorInfo;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Si es el mismo correo para multiples usuarios, solo vuelve tu arreglo en una cadena y se la seteas a $mail->addAddress asi no tienes necesidad de hacer un ciclo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error se debe a que cada vez que se llama al método `addAddress()` se  agrega un nuevo destinatario (*To:*), pero al finalizar cada ciclo no lo eliminas.

Es decir, al finalizar el ciclo `n`, en la lista de destinatarios tendrás `n` destinatarios y al destinatario en la posición `x` le habrás enviado `n - x` mails.

Más gráficamente sería:

```
// $x = 0
addAddress(mail1);
send();            // [mail1] destinatario
```

En el próximo ciclo:

```
// $x = 1
addAddress(mail2);
send();            // [mail1, mail2] destinatarios
```

Como se puede ver, a `mail1` se le envío `2` veces (*en la primera y en la segunda vuelta*).
Y así sucesivamente hasta que `$x < $i`

#### Solución:

Deberías llamar a [`clearAddresses()`](https://phpmailer.github.io/PHPMailer/classes/PHPMailer.PHPMailer.PHPMailer.html#method_clearAddresses) para eliminar todos los destinatarios que fueron agregados. Ejemplo:

```
    //... código anterior
    $mail->send();
    $mail->clearAddresses();
    //...
```